# Method and loops in C#

Tags: c#, methods

I am new to methods and loops. If someone can explain why my code isn't running properly, it would be appreciated.

1. the code first loops and writes 'Test' and the runs the second `WriteLine` afterwards.
   Shouldn't it only `WriteLine` once since the method is being called and terminated before the `WriteLine`?
2. The `WriteLine`  is writing 50 - and not counting 20 + . Why is that?

The following is my code:

```
        }
        Count(20, 50);
        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }

static void Count(int first, int last)
{
    if (first <= last)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Test!");
        Count(first + 1, last);
        Console.WriteLine(first);

    }
}
```

Comment: Where is your program "terminated"?  Also, you show no "loop".

Comment: @KirkWoll: The loop is implicit in the recursion.

Comment: But , why does it count downwards if the code is first+?

Comment: Because it stacks up the `Count()` calls, and then unrolls them in reverse order as the calls `return`.

Comment: @Robert, ah, fair enough.  But I would never in a million years refer to it as a "loop".

Comment: @Robert Harvey: Before I try to understand the reverse part. If i understood correctly the method is 'calling' itself over and over till first <= last, so it shouldnt even display the 'first' value since the method is calling itself and then stops.

Comment: @baztown execution of the method resumes after the call to itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ... the method is being called and terminated before the WriteLine

No, it's not terminating - it's calling itself *recursively*.  Every time it calls itself, it's adding a method call to the "stack".  As soon as `first==last` (which is when `first` is `50`), the last call to `Count()` in the stack will move to the next instruction, and will print `50`.  It will then terminate (because that's the last instruction) and go to the next call to `Count` in the stack.  In that case, `first` is  `49`.  That's why you see the program counting down from 50.

It's like putting cards numbered 20-50 in a pile and then reading them back after you get to 50.  The cards will start at 50 and go down.

This behavior would be more evident if you used a smaller gap (say 2 to 4) and watched the sequence of instructions in the debugger.

Comment: The card analogy , drive the point home.  But does that mean that if the method call was a number and not 'test' it will also display in reverse since its in a stack as well?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  If the first `WriteLine` printed the value of `first` then it would count up to 50 then back down to 20.